# How the two blind men can follow Jesus in Matthew 9:27 if they are blind?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-matthew

> As Jesus went on from there, two blind men followed him, calling out, “Have mercy on us, Son of David!” *- Matthew 9-27*

How it is possible that the blind men can follow Jesus without tumble and without being worn by others?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). In particular, this site is for questions about the beliefs of various Christian denominations, and the biblical basis for those beliefs. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) And on your question in particular, blind people do learn to use their other senses to get around in the world. Though your question will likely be closed, I do hope you'll stick around and read some of the other questions and answers here.

Answer (score 2):

My father was blind, and he always had someone to help him get from point a to point b. We can be pretty sure it was no different in those times.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, the question itself is not a good fit for this site, and will likely be closed. However, your answer does state briefly something that should be known about blind people: they are not helpless, and do find ways to get around in the world without their sight.